# Auto Tab to the next input field when 1 character is filled with an input field disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello friends I want to do Auto tab to next input field when fill 4 characters but 1 character and if there is a disabled input field that passes to the next enabled

How are you these questions?
[Auto tab to next input field when fill 4 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23888537/auto-tab-to-next-input-field-when-fill-4-characters)

```
<input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1" />
<input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1" />
<input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1" disabled="disabled" />
<input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1" />
<input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1" disabled="disabled"  />
<input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1" />



$(".inputs").keyup(function () {
   if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
     $(this).next('.inputs').focus();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) method([next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) method can't use since it only selects immediate adjucent sibling) with [`:enabled`](https://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/)(to get only enabled inputs) and [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)(to get first or nearest one among them) pseudo-class selectors.

```
$(".inputs").keyup(function () {
   if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
     $(this).nextAll('.inputs:enabled:first').focus();
   }
});
```

```js
$(".inputs").keyup(function() {
  if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
    $(this).nextAll('.inputs:enabled:first').focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1" />
<input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1" />
<input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1" disabled="disabled" />
<input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1" />
<input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1" disabled="disabled" />
<input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1" />
```

Comment: Excellent thank you so much for what I was looking for

Comment: @ammf18 : glad to help you :)