# ASP.NET Core MVC Jump to next textbox after x digits

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

I have 3 text fields in an ASP.NET Core MVC website. These text fields can have a maximum of 4 characters per field and should jump to the next textbox after the fourth character entered.

I have the following code, but it does not work. After entering the fourth digit the cursor stays in the textbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function jumpToNextTextbox(event, nextTextboxId) {
        if (event && event.target.value.length === event.target.maxLength) {
            document.getElementById(nextTextboxId).focus();
        }
    })
    });
</script>
```

I have inserted an alert before and in the if-query for testing, but it is not output.

The text boxes look like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-right:2px;">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Field1, new { oninput = "limitInput(this, 4); jumpToNextTextbox(event, 'field2')", @class = "form-control", maxlength = "4", htmlAttributes = new { id = "field1" } })
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-right:2px;">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Field2, new { oninput = "limitInput(this, 4); jumpToNextTextbox(event, 'field3')", @class = "form-control", maxlength = "4", htmlAttributes = new { id = "field2" } })
</div>
                    
<div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-right:2px;">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Field3, new { oninput = "limitInput(this, 4); jumpToNextTextbox(event, 'field1')", @class = "form-control", maxlength = "4", htmlAttributes = new { id = "field3" } })               
</div>
```

At which point is something still missing?

Comment: I don't think `$(document).ready()` does what you expect it to do. It doesn't register named functions in the global space. You might get better results by not wrapping that function in a `ready` call at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this working demo:

```
<div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-right:2px;" >
    <input class="inputs" asp-for="Field1" maxlength="4" />
    <input class="inputs" asp-for="Field2" maxlength="4" />
    <input class="inputs" asp-for="Field3" maxlength="4" />
</div>  

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(".inputs").keyup(function () {
            if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
                var $next = $(this).next('.inputs');
                if ($next.length)
                    $(this).next('.inputs').focus();
                else
                    $(this).blur();
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

**Gif Demo**

[image]

Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23888537/auto-tab-to-next-input-field-when-fill-4-characters).

Comment: Hi @Xinran Shen, It would work, but how can I use the class "form-control" as well?

Comment: Hi @Kojote, From my demo, I use `input` as the class of input tag , If you want to use `form-control` class, you just need to change the `input` to `form-control`, Then in javascript, change `$(".inputs")` to `$(".form-control")`